# Revision number with multi-project repo

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want several projects in one `tortoise svn` repository.

Is it possible that each project counts up with its own revision number?

Comment: RTFM about SVN-lingua! Your terms "counts up", "repository number" aren't translatable and ambiguous

Comment: If you mean revision numbers, then no, each repository has a global revision history.  Sounds like you really don't want several projects in one SVN repository.

Comment: And why do you want this?

Comment: @bahrep - just guessing: "Independent and unreated projects in one repo /hosting limitations or 'easy repo-management for for beggars'/, but want to have *nice* version-id"

Comment: @bahrep -  1) My colleagues want an `individual revision number` for **each project**.  2) **One repo for several projects**: When I reuse a module of one project in another, I get the history of that module by using `Svn copy`. Otherwise I only have a chance to get that history, if it is written in the log message.

Comment: Then you either want to use externals or stop caring about what revision IDs look like. Just imagine one day you switch to git and start having cryptographic hashes!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have sequence of numbers1-2-3 for each "project" (term not defined in SVN-world at all) for different revisions in sets: answer is short and definitive - **NO** (revisions and revisions number are global entities *per repository*)

If you want to get greatest revision for some subtree of repo, not global HEAD - **YES**, you can get it

Comment: Can you please explain the second method (not global HEAD)? Actually I want that the revision number of one sub-project is only increased if a check-in for that project occurs.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you treat revision IDs as what they are: internal identifiers that should not be given any additional meaning or use.